# How to center captionof and caption in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I will describe the problem:

Caption and captionof aren't centering table's titles. I provide a **MWE** and below an image of this problem.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionof{table}{Convergencia PM6-cluster}\label{table:convergencia_cluster_PM6}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^\circ_{SS}$} & \textbf{$\Delta G^\circ_{Packmol}$} \\ \hline
5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
20 & -64.3 & -65.0 \\ \hline
250 & -66.3 & -67.0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item \scriptsize{En la tabla se compara $\Delta G^0$ de dos métodos de solvatación (SS y Packmol) con hamiltoniano PM6. Los valores de $\Delta G^0$ se dan en Kcal/mol. La sigla SS significa Solvateshell.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Convergencia PM6-cluster}\label{table:convergencia_cluster_PM6}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^\circ_{SS}$} & \textbf{$\Delta G^\circ_{Packmol}$} \\ \hline
5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
20 & -64.3 & -65.0 \\ \hline
250 & -66.3 & -67.0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item \scriptsize{En la tabla se compara $\Delta G^0$ de dos métodos de solvatación (SS y Packmol) con hamiltoniano PM6. Los valores de $\Delta G^0$ se dan en Kcal/mol. La sigla SS significa Solvateshell.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: help!!]

As you might see, the titles aren't centered with the tables.

Any help?

Comment: You are using `threeparttable`.

Comment: mm are you saying because of the OP's title? @Johannes_B

Comment: Sorry, you are using `float`. It is not `threeparttables`  fault.

Comment: Unrelated: It has to be `{\scriptsize small text here}` (not the different placement of the opening brace).

Comment: @Johannes_B great, I will change it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: isn't this an exact duplicate of your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389565/in-trouble-with-threeparttable-centering  in my answer there I already fixed this, moving the `\caption` to its proper place inside `table` rather than `threeparttable` and arranging that it is centred?

Comment: I also fixed you `\scriptsize` usage that @Johannes_B mentioned in the answer to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I didn't notice about script :( . I added some package after your answer,  I am not sure why @DavidCarlisle

Comment: And it seems that this package was interfiering. But I understand that the questions are quite similar..@DavidCarlisle

Comment: @Johannes_B I have lost our previous chat, you have suggest how to change the numbered reactions from 1,2,3 to R1,R2,R3; would you remaind me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `\restylefloat{table}` and this works fine. I suppose whatever modifications `\restylefloat` does to `table` isn't compatible with `threeparttable`.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion of Torbjørn T., here is the MWE with a bit of further restyling. You need `\par`, for example, to get line spacing right. I also used `booktabs` and `siunitx`. I also suggest to use `microtype` and to use `\textup` for *text* in mathmode.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\floatstyle{plaintop}
%\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
%% for presentation in tex.stackov...


\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionof{table}{Convergencia PM6-cluster}\label{table:convergencia_cluster_PM6-1}
\begin{tabular}{SSS}
\toprule
{nºconf} & {$\Delta G^\circ_{SS}$} & {$\Delta G^\circ_{Packmol}$} \\ 
\midrule
5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ 
10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\
15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ 
20 & -64.3 & -65.0 \\ 
250 & -66.3 & -67.0 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item {\scriptsize En la tabla se compara $\Delta G^0$ de dos métodos de solvatación (SS y Packmol) con hamiltoniano PM6. Los valores de $\Delta G^0$ se dan en Kcal/mol. La sigla SS significa Solvateshell.\par}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you suggest to use \tabular{SSS} rather than 'centered'?

Comment: @Hernan Miraola: because it centers along the decimal dot, automatically typesets correct sign symbol ($-$ vs. -), etc. I wish I knew about it earlier!